# What is the maximum length of a Dynamic SQL statement generate within a Snowflake stored procedure?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to generate a SQL statement within a stored procedure that will contain a "BIG" Case statement.

I honestly don't how how many bytes "BIG" is, but lets say I might have several thousands of "WHEN ... THEN " lines and each line could be reasonable big (WHEN this... AND that... THEN ... END).

From the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/query-size-limits.html), I can see that there is a 1 MB limit on any statement *submitted by a client* tool but I suppose this does not apply to dynamic SQL generated within a stored procedure... since it is server side.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote and modified a stored procedure to test this. It built a simple SQL statement that did a select 'xxxx' and increased the fill on the x characters. The code caught any SQL errors and returned the size of hitting the first error. It never did. It kept working and I kept increasing the increment size until finally the JavaScript (not SQL) reported a string size exceeded limit, which is 256 MB.

That didn't convince me that statements that long would necessarily do anything meaningful, so I modified the SP to test it with your cited example of a large case statement. That's when I hit what is probably a more significant limit. It reported "maximum number of expressions in a list exceeded. Expected at most 16,384.

I then tested it in blocks of 1000 when clauses (XS warehouse, took a few minutes), and unexpectedly it hit the limit between 8000 and 9000 when clauses. Even though the case statement had 9000 when clauses, the error said it had 18,002 expressions in the list, so it appears that's including each literal value in the when statement as one expression.

Based on this testing, you may be more likely to encounter the expression limitation in the case block before you hit the internal size limit for a statement.

Test SP code is here (monitor results in Query History):

```
create or replace procedure TEST_SQL_LEN()
returns float
language javascript
execute as caller
as
$$

    var sql = "";
    var caseBlock = "";

    for (var i = 1000; i < 100000; i = i + 1000) {
        sql = 
`select 
    ${i} as I,
    case ` + buildCase(i) + "\end as result";
    
        try {
            // To show in history page how many case statements
            getResultSet('select ' + i); 
            // To test that many conditions in a case block
            getResultSet(sql);
        }
        catch(e) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
    
function buildCase(n) {
    var s = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        s += "when I = " + i + " then " + i + "\n";
    }
    return s;
}

function getResultSet(sql){
    cmd1 = {sqlText: sql};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd1);
    var rs;
    rs = stmt.execute();
    return rs;
}

$$;

call TEST_SQL_LEN();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This is VERY interesting and slightly worrying for what I had in mind. I have some code that does something quite close to this (generating CASE statements...). It clearly shows that the answer is "Maybe..." so I'll do some serious testing before committing too much!

Again MANY THANKS

Answer (score 1):

have in mind, that on top of the actual code you have compilation memory limitations - so the fact you CAN write 256 meg line of code doesn't mean you will be able to execute it. Also, Snowflake compilation also depends on the data, not just the code itself, so the same code might still run on a 10-row table and then fail on a 1000-row.

Are you sure there's no easier way to solve the actual problem?